# ColdFusion 10 Submit/next button

Tags: html, button, coldfusion

Ive recently upgraded to ColdFusion 10 from CF7 and there is somethign wrong with my submit/next buttons in my code and Im not sure what changed. Im hoping another pair of eyes can help me with this. Every page I have uses my template of "Actionbuttons" which puts in the bottom of the my "Back" "Next" and "Cancel" buttons. Since Ive gone to CF10 the "next" button does not work correctly. It DOES advance to the next page BUT the page is blank white, and when I view source of the page, my code is a generic white HTML code and not the code inside my .CFM file. Now in CF7 this works exactly how it should, it takes the data you input and uses it and goes to the next page. Now in CF10 The "Next" button just goes to a blank white page and doesnt pull the code off the .CFM page it is told to.

```
<!-- 
  BACK/NEXT/CANCEL Buttons
-->
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR="#D4D0C8">
<TD COLSPAN="2">
<HR>
<TABLE BORDER="0" WIDTH="100%" BGCOLOR="#D4D0C8">
 <TR>
  <TD WIDTH="80%"></TD>
  <TD><INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" DISABLED VALUE="  < Back  "></TD>
<cfif isdefined("FINALWIZPAGE")>
  <TD><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Finish"></TD>
<CFELSE>
  <TD><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="  Next >  "></TD>
</CFIF>
  <TD></TD>
  <TD><INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="  Cancel  "></TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>
</TR></TD>
```

Im going to go ahead and Add the .CFM page that uses these "actionsbuttons" maybe that will help.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE>Project Directory Wizard</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<CENTER>


<CFINCLUDE TEMPLATE="HEADER.CFM">
<!---<CFINCLUDE TEMPLATE="BUTTONBAR.CFM"> --->
<CFINCLUDE TEMPLATE="MAINAREA.CFM">

<!---
Main Content
--->

<FORM ACTION="DIRECTORY2.CFM" METHOD="POST">

<TABLE WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%" BGCOLOR="#D4D0C8">
<TR><TD>
Please select a company directory to place the new projects:<BR>

<CFDIRECTORY action="list" DIRECTORY="\\SERVERNAME\shared\PROJECTS"
    NAME="myDirectory"
    SORT="Name ASC">
<CFPARAM NAME="SELECTEDDIRECTORY" DEFAULT="">

<SELECT NAME="MAINDIRECTORY">
 <OPTION>
<CFOUTPUT QUERY="myDirectory">
<CFIF TYPE IS "Dir">
 <CFIF "#NAME#" IS "#UCASE(SELECTEDDIRECTORY)#">
  <OPTION VALUE="#NAME#" SELECTED>#Name#
 <CFELSE>
 </CFIF>
  <OPTION VALUE="#NAME#">#Name#

</CFIF>
</CFOUTPUT>
</SELECT>
<A HREF="./addnewclient.cfm">Add New Client</a> (if not listed)<br>
<BR>


<BR>
Project Name:<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" MAXLENGTH="20" SIZE="20" NAME="DIRTOCREATE" VALUE="">

<BR><BR>

</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<CFINCLUDE TEMPLATE="ACTIONBUTTONS.CFM">
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer that without a bit more information.  What happens when you click the submit buttons, do you have some javascript handling a redirect, are you posting a form, or what?  We probably need to see more relevant code (and less <td> stuff)

Comment: When I click the submit button it goes to the target page in the URL, so the URL is pointed to where it needs to be but the actual page itself is white and the source is this generic:

Comment: If you enable debugging, do you see the form variables?

Comment: You if you have that checked off.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the cfm handlers for the webserver aren't correctly configured.

When the setup isn't configured correctly it will procces the default page (index.cfm for example), but not any other coldfusion page you request from the server.

You might want to try to run the webserver configuration tool again and don't forget to add a virtal folder named 'jakarta' pointing to the wsconfig folder (more information here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18a15-7ffb.html)

Comment: That sounds exactly like my problem. Now when you say Virtual Folder? Im not sure I follow that or what that is.

Comment: Can you tell me what webserver you are using? Apache or IIS? or something else.

A virtual folder is basically a folder that points to a different location than your webroot. http://mywebsite.com/test for example, might point to C:\bla\bla on your server

Comment: I am using IIS7, So I am trying to access this from my sharepoint. Which is http://sharepoint.com/Divisions/ENGTECH/ProjectDirectoryWizard/dir_startup.cfm

Comment: Oke, then it should be relatively easy to add the virtual folder. Just right click on your website in IIS7 and there you will see the option to add a virtual directory. After that you can specify the alias(the folder name) and the directory (path to the wsconfig/{somenumber} folder)

Comment: Alright I have added my Sharepoint through the CF webserver tool, I have created the Virtual directory off my sharepoint in IIS7 that points to my C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\2. Now I still get my first screen and when I click next I get: The website cannot display the page) Instead of my blank white page that I was getting some thing still isnt adding up.

Comment: All the handler mappings are there also

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by 'added my Sharepoint through the CF webserver tool' If you run the webserver configuration tool of Coldfusion you have to give the information of the IIS webserver . After the configuration is done you can create a website in IIS, add the virtual folder called jakarta and you should be good to go. You can also open the 'handler mappings' of the webserver and check if you can see the mappings for .cfm and .cfc files .  The easiest way is to click on the website and you should find it in the icon list. **Ignore my comment part about the mappings**

Comment: My Sharepoint is the website created in IIS. When I use the webserver config. tool of coldfusion it asks what IIS Website to add, with a drop down and I have the choice, of All, or my Sharepoint. ALL was already created so now I created one for my Sharepoint. Thats why I think I have C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\1 and a C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\2. And in my IIS website(sharepoint) there is a Jakarta folder mapped to C:\ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\2

Comment: Oke, clear. One other thing that I would like to know is, can you run other .cfm pages when you directly call them, http://mywebsite.com/test.cfm for example. If you can run that, then we know the problem probably lies not with your server configuration

Comment: Yes, I can pull any code and place it in that first file and it will ALWAYS open, but it will not advance to the next page.